# How to loop through a text file and return a card object every two lines?

Tags: java, loops

So, I've got a text file formatted like this which I have tried to turn into single cards and put them into an array, I have put the textfile and classes below to show you what I've done:

```
a
h
2
h
3
h
4
h
5
h
6
h
7
h
8
h
9
h
t
h
j
h
q
h
k
h
a
d
2
d
3
d
4
d
5
d
6
d
7
d
8
d
9
d
t
d
j
d
q
d
k
d
a
c
2
c
3
c
4
c
5
c
6
c
7
c
8
c
9
c
t
c
j
c
q
c
k
c
a
s
2
s
3
s
4
s
5
s
6
s
7
s
8
s
9
s
t
s
j
s
q
s
k
s
```

So now with help from the comment I've added the following classes:

Card:

```
public class Card {
    public String number;
    public String suit;

    public Card(String n, String s) {
        number = n;
        suit = s;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return number + suit;
    }
}
```

and deck (unfinished currently) -

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Deck {
  private ArrayList < Card > cards;

  public Deck() {
    cards = new ArrayList < Card > ();
  }

  public List < Card > buildDeck() throws IOException {

    List < String > cardLines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("cards.txt"));

    // build card objects
    List < Card > result = new ArrayList < Card > ();
    for (int i = 0; i < cardLines.size(); i += 2) { //if lines read are smaller than file then read for another card
      cards.add(new Card(cardLines.get(i), cardLines.get(i + 1))); //add new card to cards array
    }
    return result;
  }

  /*public void shuffle() {
        // fill in
    }*/

}
```

And this will be my GUI class -

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Game {
  public Scanner scan;

  public void runMenu() {
    String response;
    do {
      printMenu();
      System.out.println("What would you like to do:");
      scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      response = scan.nextLine().toUpperCase();
      switch (response) {
        case "1":
          buildDeck();
          break;
        case "2":
          ShuffleCards();
          break;
        case "3":
          DealCard();
          break;
        case "4":
          MoveToPrevious();
          break;
        case "5":
          Move2PilesBack();
          break;
        case "6":
          AmalgamateInMiddle();
          break;
        case "7":
          PlayforMe();
          break;
        case "8":
          ShowLowScores();
        case "Q":
          break;
        default:
          System.out.println("Try again");
      }
    } while (!(response.equals("Q")));
  }

  private void ShowLowScores() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }

  private void PlayforMe() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }

  private void AmalgamateInMiddle() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }

  private void Move2PilesBack() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }

  private void MoveToPrevious() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }

  private void DealCard() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }

  private void ShuffleCards() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }

  private void buildDeck() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }

  private void printMenu() {
    System.out.println("1 -  Print the pack ");
    System.out.println("2 -  Shuffle");
    System.out.println("3 -  Deal a card");
    System.out.println("4 -  Move last pile onto previous one");
    System.out.println("5 -  Move last pile back over two piles");
    System.out.println("6 -  Amalgamate piles in the middle");
    System.out.println("7 -  Play for me");
    System.out.println("8 -  Show low scores");
    System.out.println("q - Quit");
  }
}
```

So after my other errors now appear to be fixed that I've had help with from comments, how can I print out the arraylist in the deck class into my GUI class option 1, thanks!

Comment: Where is your **Code** ??

Comment: I don't currently have the code, I thought somebody might be able to give me some guidance on how to write a loop that I could use to get the card values. I'm just starting my first class, a card class and I'm pretty out of my depth with this.

Comment: @irrossi look at the `Scanner` class...

Comment: Will do thank brso, will post my code here when I manage to write something :)

Comment: You have to either indicate that buildDeck throws an Exception (Look at main in my answer), or you need to add try/catch code to your buildDeck method.

Comment: What is cards doing in the constructor of Deck()?  Do you have a class variable called cards also?  Because in buildDeck, you have a local variable of cards.

Comment: No, I have a class called Card which is above. But I put the ArrayList 'cards' in the constructor because I want to print out the ArrayList of the sorted cards later on, onto a GUI where the user selects an option called "Print Deck".

Comment: I will show you my future other class I am currently designing aswell to show you what I mean, I've put it above now :), where I've put private void buildDeck in my GUI class, I want to print the ArrayList out there :).

Comment: Ok... Look at the Card class, the Card has two class variables (number and suit).  Those two class variables are reused in the toString() method.  In your Deck class, make cards a class variable.  Currently, in the constructor you just made a local variable to the constructor and in builddeck() you made a local variable.  Local in that only that method will access the variable and then the variable is gone.  When you make it a class variable, it is accessible throughout the class, just like how number & suit are accessible in the Card class.

Comment: Thanks for responding, I figured I'd accidently created varible duplication, I called the local arraylist in build deck 'cards' when the class arraylist was called the same thing. I think this will work now, I've put my new code in the question, how would I now print that arraylist in my GUI class? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something to get you going as to retrieving the cards from your file.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<String> cardLines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(yourCardFile));

    // Build your card objects from the file
    List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < cardLines.size(); i += 2) {
        cards.add(new Card(cardLines.get(i), cardLines.get(i + 1)));
    }

    // Print the cards out
    for (Card card : cards) {
        System.out.println(card);
    }

    // Do what you need to do after you have your cards
}

public static class Card {
    public String number;
    public String suit;

    public Card(String n, String s) {
        number = n;
        suit = s;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return number + suit;
    }
}
```

Results (Not all cards are screen captured):

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Where you put yourCardFile, would I put "cards.txt" (the name of my card file).

Comment: with quotations around it?

Comment: @Irrossi If you have the full path to your card file in a variable, you can just use the variable.  If you don't and want to hard code your full path, you'll have to use the quotations.

Comment: @Irrossi Kindly check my answer if it has solved your question. :-)

Comment: @Irrossi Put this code in your question and not as a comment.  Make sure it's formatted so that it's readable.

Comment: HI, just added the code, some problems remain which I don't understand at moment if you can help :)

Comment: Ok thanks fixed that problem, but I'm now getting a new problem which says the value cards is not being used, but it is in buildDeck :/

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Files.readAllLines`:

```
Iterator<String> it = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(...)).iterator();
for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
    String number = it.next();
    String suit = it.next();
    // ...
}
```

Or another way is using `Scanner`, which is pretty much similar.